# Existing class to get property chain in ActionScript3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4

Is there an existing class in Flash or Flex that gets the value from an object from it's property chain?

For example, something like this:

```
private function labelFunction(item:Object, column:GridColumn):String {
     // where dataField equals "fields.status.name"
     var value:String = PropertyChain.getValue(field, column.dataField);
     return value;
}
```

~~~ **Update** ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
I found this private method in the Binding class as well that could probably be used in a custom class:

```
/**
 *  @private
 */
private static function getFirstWord(destStr:String):String
{
    // indexPeriod and indexBracket will be equal only if they
    // both are -1.
    var indexPeriod:int = destStr.indexOf(".");
    var indexBracket:int = destStr.indexOf("[");
    if (indexPeriod == indexBracket)
        return destStr;

    // Get the characters leading up to the first period or
    // bracket.
    var minIndex:int = Math.min(indexPeriod, indexBracket);
    if (minIndex == -1)
        minIndex = Math.max(indexPeriod, indexBracket);

    return destStr.substr(0, minIndex);
}
```

Comment: If you have an `Object` and a property chain, why can't you access the value directly? object.chain.of.properties OR object[stringContainingPropertyChain]

Comment: This,   

 field["fields.status.name"] does not work. As for accessing the value directly that defeats the purpose of the question. :) The GridColumn class lets you enter in a property chain String in the dataField property. So I want to reuse that since at runtime I don't want to hard code a value into every item renderer I create.

Comment: Now I get it, lumping that property chain as one string with the dots in it wouldn't work. The answer below is spot on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's an existing function. But it's very easy to build one, and it need not be restricted to generic `Object` sources, as any member of *any* object can be retrieved by name using square bracket notation. This simple version doesn't do any validation:

```
public static function getByName(root:*, member:String):* {
    var memlist:Array = member.split('.');
    var temp:* = root;
    for(var i:uint = 0; i < memlist.length; i++)
        temp = temp[memlist[i]];
    return temp;
}

// And you can use this even on strongly-typed values, such as a MovieClip:
trace("stageWidth =", SomeUtil.getByName(mc, "stage.stageWidth"));
```

Comment: Great. I'm going to give it some more time before accepting this answer.